# How do you sync firefox addon/extension preferences?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, synchronization

What is the format for declaring that an addon's preferences should sync across firefox installations? I see a short [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_Sync/Syncing_custom_preferences) that you should create `services.sync.prefs.sync.extension.frobnaz.foobar` but how should that be entered in the package.json that defines the addon's preferences? For instance, say I've defined a preference there:

```
"preferences": [{"name": "show_xyz",
                 "type": "bool",
                 "title": "Show XYZ",
                 "value": true}]
```

In firefox's `about:config` this is ultimately translated into the preference `extensions.<addon id>@jetpack.show_xyz`. So how should `services.sync.prefs.sync.*` preferences be created?

Answer (score 1):

You have to deal with this programmatically, through the `preferences/service` module.

```js
var ps = require('sdk/preferences/service');
var addonid = require('sdk/self').id;

var simpleprefs = ps.keys('extensions.' + addonid);

simpleprefs.forEach(function(prefname){
  ps.set('services.sync.prefs.sync.extensions.' + addonid + '.' + prefname, true)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This guy here syncs greasemonkey prefs, i think you can use it:
https://gist.github.com/LouCypher/3193779

```
var prefs = Services.prefs;
var prefArray = prefs.getChildList("greasemonkey.scriptvals", {});
for (var i = 0; i < prefArray.length; i++) {
prefs.setBoolPref("services.sync.prefs.sync." + prefArray[i], true);
}
```